# How do I split data across multiple spreadsheets in Excel using C# code?

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I am trying to create an application that can extract a ton of data from a txt file 3000+ lines.

I have already filtered the data etc and I am able to write everything into the excel spreadsheet in the correct way. My problem is that I want to split the data over multiple sheets and limit each sheet to a specific number of data rows (The exact value is a number chosen between 100-1000)

I have ended up with an output that creates the correct number of sheets, but it outputs all the lines of data into all the sheets instead of splitting them up over all the sheets.

For clarity:
Example: I have 950 lines of data. Thus the output should be 100 data rows in 8 sheets and the 9th should have the last 50.

What I currently get is: 950 data rows in all 9 sheets.

Here is my code that controls the Excel creation.

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filename, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
                    {
                        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
                        workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
                        var workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
                        Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

                        for (int i = 0; i < Amount; i++)
                        {
                            
                            Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
                            {
                                Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                                SheetId = ((uint)(i + 1)),
                                Name = "Data" + (i + 1)
                            };
                            
                            sheets.Append(sheet);
                            var HeadRow = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().AppendChild(new Row());//new Row
                            HeadRow.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Type"), DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String) });
                            HeadRow.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Description"), DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String) });
                            HeadRow.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Time"), DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String) });
                            HeadRow.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Date"), DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String) });
                            for (int j = 0 + (i * (int)OrgAmount); j < ((i + 1) * (int)OrgAmount); j++)//Rows
                            {
                                if (j == LineCount)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }

                                var row = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().AppendChild(new Row());//new Row
                                var cell1 = row.AppendChild(new Cell());//Type
                                var cell2 = row.AppendChild(new Cell());//Description
                                var cell3 = row.AppendChild(new Cell());//Time
                                var cell4 = row.AppendChild(new Cell());//Date

                                cell1.CellValue = new CellValue(LineType[j]);
                                cell1.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                                cell2.CellValue = new CellValue(LineDesc[j]);
                                cell2.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                                cell3.CellValue = new CellValue(LineTime[j]);
                                cell3.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                                cell4.CellValue = new CellValue(LineDate[j]);
                                cell4.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                            }
                            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
                        }
                        spreadsheetDocument.Close();
                    }
```

Please help me since I don't know where I messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed myself in the end.

Here is what I did:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filename, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
                    {
                        //Create workbook, workbookPart and sheets
                        WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
                        workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                        Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
                        for (int i = 0; i < Amount; i++)
                        {
                            //New worksheetPart, worksheet and sheet for each sheet to be addressed seperately
                            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
                            var workSheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
                            //Dynamically create a sheet according to options chosen in form
                            Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
                            {
                                Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                                SheetId = ((uint)(i + 1)),
                                Name = "Data" + (i + 1)
                            };
                            
                            //Header row creation
                            var HeadRow = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().AppendChild(new Row());//new Row
                            HeadRow.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Type"), DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String) });
                            HeadRow.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Description"), DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String) });
                            HeadRow.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Time"), DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String) });
                            HeadRow.AppendChild(new Cell() { CellValue = new CellValue("Date"), DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String) });
                            for (int j = 0 + (i * (int)OrgAmount); j < ((i + 1) * (int)OrgAmount); j++)//Rows
                            {
                                if (j == LineCount)//If final line is reached before loop end, then break loop
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                //Initialise new row cells
                                var row = workSheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().AppendChild(new Row());//new Row
                                var cell1 = row.AppendChild(new Cell());//Type
                                var cell2 = row.AppendChild(new Cell());//Description
                                var cell3 = row.AppendChild(new Cell());//Time
                                var cell4 = row.AppendChild(new Cell());//Date
                                //Write data to cells, extracted from text file
                                cell1.CellValue = new CellValue(LineType[j]);
                                cell1.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                                cell2.CellValue = new CellValue(LineDesc[j]);
                                cell2.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                                cell3.CellValue = new CellValue(LineTime[j]);
                                cell3.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                                cell4.CellValue = new CellValue(LineDate[j]);
                                cell4.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                            }
                            sheets.Append(sheet);//Append the written sheet to workbook sheets
                        }
                        workbookPart.Workbook.Save();//save workbook
                        spreadsheetDocument.Close();//Close document
                    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).